# Weird issue: Custom wordpress widget being confused as text widget

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress appears to be confusing my widget with the "Text Widget".

On my widget settings page, it is displayed as

```
About Author (the name of my widget)
Arbitrary text or HTML (the description of the text widget)
```

When I register my widget with wordpress, it removes all widgets in the "Available Widgets" row from use.

When I open my widget to edit it, the final textarea (called about-author) is filled with the HTML of the widget settings page

When I put in content to the forms and click save, the form changes to that of the text widget (none of what I entered is saved either, the widget just goes back to "Available Widgets" when I refresh the page).

Here's the html the widget form contains when opening it (it's too long to paste here):
[Weird HTML](http://pastebin.com/EaYcs53n)

Here's my widget code (in functions.php in my theme):

```
class Ms_About_Author_Widget extends WP_Widget {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct('ms_about_author_widget', 'About Author',
            array(
                'classname' => 'ms_about_author_widget',
                'description' =>
                'A signature block containing your name and summary',
                ));

    // $this->widget_options['before_widget'] = sprintf($this->widget_options['before_title'],
    //  'authored-by', 'itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"');
}

public function widget($args, $instance) {
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    echo '<table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="author-image">
                        <img src="'.get_avatar('*my email*', 140).'"
                        width="70" height="70" itemprop="image">
                    </td>
                    <td class="author-bio">
                        <h3>Authored by <span itemprop="name">'.$instance['title'].'</span></h3><a href="https://twitter.com/'.$instance['twitter-name'].'" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow</a>
                        <p itemprop="description"><img src="'.get_avatar('*my email*', 140).'"
                        width="70" height="70">'.$instance['about-author'].'</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>';
    echo $args['after_widget'];

}

public function form($instance) {
    echo '
    <p>
        <label for="'.$this->get_field_name('title').'">Name:</label>
        <input class="widefat" id="'.$this->get_field_id('title').'" name="'.$this->get_field_name('title').'" type="text" value="">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="'.$this->get_field_name('twitter-name').'">Twitter Handle:</label>
        <input class="widefat" id="'.$this->get_field_id('twitter-name').'" name="'.$this->get_field_name('twitter-name').'" type="text" value="">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="'.$this->get_field_name('about-author').'">About You:</label>
        <textarea class="widefat" id="'.$this->get_field_id('about-author').'" name="'.$this->get_field_name('about-author').'" value="">
    </p>';
}

public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    $instance = array();

    $instance['title'] = (!empty($new_instance['title'] )) ? strip_tags($new_instance['title']) : '';
    $instance['twitter-name'] = (!empty($new_instance['twitter-name'] )) ? strip_tags($new_instance['twitter-name']) : '';
    $instance['about-author'] = (!empty($new_instance['about-author'] )) ? strip_tags($new_instance['about-author']) : '';

    return $instance;
}
}

 function ms_register_widgets() {
    register_widget('Ms_About_Author_Widget');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'ms_register_widgets');
```

Any ideas on what this is or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

/facepalm

.....

The issue was an unclosed `</textarea>`...

Only found out after rewriting the whole thing.